# Loggin in ssh server: Permission denied, please try again

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to login to my ssh server using a username and password, but I get this error after entering the correct password:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I *can* login using a pubkey on another machine, though, but I have NOT disabled regular password authentication. The only thing I disabled was root logins.

Here's my sshd_config file:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts

RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options 
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60 
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication. Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes 
IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I've added the last 2 lines in a latest attempt at getting it to work. (I have them on my other vps, and they work there)

Here's the listing of the ~/.ssh/ directory of my user:

```
ls -la /home/skerit/.ssh
total 16
drwx------ 2 skerit skerit 4096 2011-06-25 15:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 skerit skerit 4096 2011-07-07 21:05 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 skerit skerit 1882 2011-06-25 15:15 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 skerit skerit 884 2011-06-23 22:59 known_hosts
```

This is the output of /usr/sbin/sshd -d:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user skerit service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "skerit"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "82.197.70.70"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user skerit service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/skerit/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/skerit/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/skerit/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for skerit from 82.197.70.70 port 57154 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user skerit service ssh-connection method password
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1
debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for skerit: Authentication failure
Failed password for skerit from 82.197.70.70 port 57154 ssh2
```

I then tried to login to the ssh server FROM the ssh server (locally) using THE SAME username and password, and it worked. This was in the auth.log file:

```
Jul 8 12:21:50 vpsnl1 sshd[27298]: debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key': No such file or directory
Jul 8 12:21:50 vpsnl1 sshd[27298]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Jul 8 12:22:16 vpsnl1 sshd[27298]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=82.197.70.70 user=
skerit
Jul 8 12:23:50 vpsnl1 sshd[27439]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 8 12:23:50 vpsnl1 sshd[27439]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 8 12:24:07 vpsnl1 sshd[27458]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Jul 8 12:24:14 vpsnl1 sshd[27458]: Accepted password for skerit from 127.0.0.1 port 57667 ssh2
Jul 8 12:24:14 vpsnl1 sshd[27458]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user skerit by (uid=0)
Jul 8 12:24:25 vpsnl1 sshd[27471]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: disconnected by user
Jul 8 12:24:25 vpsnl1 sshd[27458]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user skerit
```

Comment: Could you add your ssh-config?

Comment: Alright, config file added!

Comment: How about permisions on .ssh? Could you post ls -la ~/.ssh on the server?

Comment: Ok, I've added the listing of the files of the user I'm trying to login as.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your password is correct? Plus: you can get a lot of detail from ssh by putting it into debug mode (add a line `LogLevel DEBUG` to the sshd_config and reload ssh). Then inspect the auth log.

Comment: Authorized_keys shouldn't be world-readable I think, but it doesn't explain why you can't login with password. Can you do `su skerit` in your account?

Comment: Yes, but su-ing into skerit from root does not require a password. However: when trying to ssh-ing locally it does work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you certain that the user account you're attempting to access is correctly configured?  If you log in as root on the system, can you `su` to the user account?

```
# su - username
```

What do you see in your logs after a failed connection attempt?  On many systems, sshd will log to something `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log`.  Also, I note that you have `PasswordAuthentication` enabled but `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` disabled.  Do you see the same behavior if you enable `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`?

Here are some general diagnostic steps to use when you have ssh problems:

- Enable verbose diagnostics in ssh:

  ```
  ssh -v host.example.com
  ```

  This will cause the client to output a variety of diagnostic messages as it negotiates the connection.  This will often provide a clue to the problem.
- Run the server in debug mode.

  On your server, stop sshd, then run it from the command line like this:

  ```
  /usr/sbin/sshd -d
  ```

  This will produce verbose debug logging on `stderr` that will very often contain useful information.

If neither of these helps you figure out what's going on, would you add the output to your question?

Comment: Ok, I've added the output. Basically: when I tro a remote login it says the password isn't good, when I try a local login it says the password is ok and lets me in.

Comment: It *WAS* the password. I changed the password through a web console (some java application) and even though the entered password was IDENTICAL to what I typed in my putty console, somehow the ascii values must have differed. I changed it to something simpler, logged in the correct way through putty, and changed it back again. Now it works.

Comment: @skerit - probably had a character encoding issue, then - maybe UTF8 vs ASCII?

Comment: Glad to hear things are working!

Comment: Had the same problem as @skerit after doing a password change from DigitalOcean's web console.